# invalid child element 'MvcBuildViews' in namespace for nopCommerce 2.65

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

I have downloaded nopCommerce latest version with MVC/Razor but I am not able to open the project as it gives error as `invalid child element 'MvcBuildViews' in namespace`.

I tried to remove it and then tried to open the project but it does not allow to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it by installing MVC 3